# Webpack: Adding React into Flask, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, npm, webpack

I want to link react project to python Flask, so I choose using webpack as a solution.

But, it have the **500 Internal Server Error** when loading the webpacked react file after running the executable code:

[500 Internal Server Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OloNG.png)

The executable code is as below:

```
webpack
app.py
```

I don't know where is wrong in the current structure.

This project is constructed like below:

```
templete
|--- index.html
static
web
|--- app.js
|--- containers
    |--- First.js
    |---Second.js
app.py
package.json
webpack.config.js
requirements.txt
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin  = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: [
        '@babel/polyfill',
        "./web/app.js"
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "flask_react_router.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static"),
        publicPath: "/static/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                        plugins: [
                            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {legacy: true}],
                            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {loose: true}]
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "flask_react_router.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

app.js:

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import First from './containers/First';
import Second from './containers/Second';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path='/first' component={ First } />
        <Route exact path='/second' component={ Second } />
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

First.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class First extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello First</div>
        )
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="kimkkikki">
    <title>Flask React Router</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='flask_react_router.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='flask_react_router.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def web(path):
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

Can someone help this problem?

Comment: instead of `app.run(host='127.0.0.1')` try this `app.run(host='127.0.0.1:5000')`

Comment: or maybe because of case-sensitive, in your address you wrote `first` but in your file is `First`